# Изменить BorderColor panel'и. C#

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть panel, у которой стоит BorderStyle = FixedSingle.
[image: Panek]

Я хочу изменить цвет границы, но в конструкторе ничего нет.

Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Пошлядите [тут](https://www.fordevs.com/2009/12/how-to-set-border-color-of-a-panel-in-c.html), [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996104/how-to-change-panel-border-color) - возможно поможет. А вообще юзайте `wpf` если вам нужны стили...

Comment: Это системный цвет. Он одинаков во всех приложениях, запущенных на данной конкретной ОС. Его может изменить пользователь, выбрав желаемую цветовую схему (естественно, цвета изменятся во всех приложениях). / Если всё же хотите сделать собственную рамочку, то задайте `BorderStyle.None` и рисуйте бордер нужного цвета с помощью [Graphics.DrawRectangle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawrectangle) в событии [Paint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint)